# Web Component: How to access Shadow DOM through script in parent tag?

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom

I want to access a tag in Shadow DOM using a JavaScript code which is loaded in the importing file.

Say, my custom element has a div

```
<div>I am custom element</div>
```

I want to access this tag from the script that is loaded in the importing file of the custom element

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="x-component.html">
</head>
<body>
    <div>I am parent element</div>
    <x-component></x-component>
    <script>
       $('div').html('I replaced all div html');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Assume jQuery is used in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadow root is accessible via `#querySelector(sel).shadowRoot`. The example below shows the difference between acessing native divs and those in ShadowDOM.

```
  // native divs
  var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(
               document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')
             );

  divs.forEach(function(e) {
    e.innerHTML = 'CHANGED';
  });

  // access shadowed divs
  var shadowDivs = Array.prototype.slice.call(
                     document.querySelector('x-component').shadowRoot.children
                   ); // or .querySelector('div')

  shadowDivs.forEach(function(e) {
    if(e.constructor === HTMLDivElement) { // divs only
      e.innerHTML = 'CHANGED IN SHADOW';
    }
  });
```

Live preview: http://plnkr.co/edit/lNeTWF28jHP01ORCcAgU?p=preview